# How do you access the data returned by a controller when run in unit tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, nunit

I have a Asp .net core 2.2 web api.  I am trying to set up unit testing on a number of the controllers.   I have it working to he point where it does call the controller

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet("list")]
public ActionResult Get([FromQuery] string q = null)
    {
        if (q != null)
            return Ok(new ClientListResponse(ClientHelper.FindClientByClientIdOrClientName(_configurationDbContext.Clients, q)));

        return Ok(new ClientListResponse(_configurationDbContext.Clients.ToList()));
    }
```

**Test calling it**

```
var allClients = controller.Get();
```

**Issue**

Now when i look at it in debug everything looks fine. I can see that value contains the correct object being returned.

[image]

However when it try to access the variables they don't exist.

[image]

I am suspecting that this has something to do with the response being an ActionResult.  I have tried to convert it to everything i can think of.

How do you access the data returned by a controler when run in unit tests?

Comment: There's some good info on the docs on how to test controllers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @DavidG yes thats actually one of the pages i am following but i dont seam to have Assert.IsAssignableFrom this method so it wasnt working.

Comment: Check the tags its tagged NUnit.

Comment: Oops my apologies. NUnit should have that method too, I've checked here and it does. Which version of NUnit are you using?

Comment: The newest probably i am not that familiar with unit testing this is a 20% playing project.   No even sure i should be using Nunit or Xnuit for this.

Comment: Either is fine. I use XUnit because it's the first one I tried, no other reason! I'm really confused as to why it's not showing for you though. I'm really no keen on the answer given below, it feels rather brittle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast it to an `OkObjectResult`.

In ours:

```
var controller = SetupAdminTestsForPassword();
var result = controller.ValidateTokenForUserCreation(new ValidateUserTokenRequest() { token = "VALIDCREATEUSERTOKEN"});
var okResult = result as OkObjectResult;

// assert
Assert.IsNotNull(okResult);
Assert.IsNotNull(okResult.Value);
Assert.IsNotNull(okResult.Value as ValidateUserTokenResponse);
Assert.IsTrue((okResult.Value as ValidateUserTokenResponse).IsValid);
```

We're also using dotnet core 2.2 and Moq for tests.

Comment: var m = okResult.Value as ClientListResponse;
Assert.AreEqual(m.Clients.Count, 10);   For seeing the data returned.  thanks